# Elasticsearch query to match values from list of values in Excel [Python]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, boolean-logic, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I have a list of values for example:

```
id_list=[1111,2222,3333,4444,5555]
```

Now I want to match those ids in that `id_list` to match with some information stored in Elasticsearch having the same id no. I'm thinking to use for loop to loop all the ids to match using the ES query, but I not sure how exactly to do that.

I know that using For Loop can run through all values in the list

```
for id in id_list:
print(id)
```

I able to search the id one-by-one using below ES query:

```
query={"bool":
{must":
[{"match":{"id_list":"1111"}}]
}}
```

Any possible way to include loop function so that I dont have to key-in the id manually like above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) from elasticsearch to query list of ids:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id_list": [1111,2222,3333,4444,5555]
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated Based on comments:**

As mentioned in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup) maximum of 65,536 terms.

> By default, Elasticsearch limits the terms query to a maximum of
> 65,536 terms. This includes terms fetched using terms lookup. You can
> change this limit using the index.max_terms_count setting.

Comment: Hi Sagar Patel, appreciate your suggestion!

What if the list could go up till hundreds of ids? It would be tons of work to key-in all the ids in that id_list. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: You can send max 65,536 ids in terms query as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup). alternatively, you can hit parallel search request to Elasticsearch with 100 ids per request. I will suggest to go with single request if you have less ids. Also, you can do performance test and based on that you can decided.